# String to Array with evaluate() fails

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How does one convert a string to an array

```
<cfscript>
    stResult = {    strData = "[1,2,3,4,5,6]"
                 ,  arInstant = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
               };

    //stResult.arData = evaluate(stResult.strData);  // this does not work
    //stResult.arData = evaluate("#stResult.strData#"); // nor does this

    writedump(stResult);
</cfscript>
```

I am trying to get something that looks like arInstant.

Is there a better way than striping the `[]`, converting to a list, then converting to an array?

Comment: you have not said which CFML engine and version you are using, this may be important. fwiw your code works as expected in Railo 4.0.2.000

Comment: Using `listToArray` with multiple delimiters ie `[,]` would certainly do it. Assuming there is a good reason for storing it as a string and not an array initially..

Comment: I am using Adobe CF 9.02

Comment: `deserializeJson(Result.Data)` ?

Comment: @PeterBoughton : To do that approach, It would have to be something like `deserializeJSON("{myData:#strData#}").myData`

Comment: I do like the added flexibility.

Comment: What? No it wouldn't! deserializeJson works directly on a JSON array and outputs a CF array, no structs/objects required/involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

evaluate() should generally be avoided (ref: [1](http://cfprimer.blogspot.co.uk/2005/03/avoid-evaluate.html), [2](http://www.danielgaspar.com/blog/2010/05/coldfusions-evaluate/), [3](http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/3/17/ditch_coldfusion_evaluate)).  How about trying:

```
stResult.arData = ListToArray(stResult.strData, "[],");
```

This is treating the whole string as a list, with possible delimiters of `[` and `]` and `,`

It should give you an array with 6 elements in it.

Of course, it seems that your `stResult.arInstant` already has what you need... what are you trying to do?

Comment: The string that is formatted with `[]` comes in from an external process. arInstant is the goal

Answer (score 4):

Your data is a [JSON](http://json.org/) string so use **[deserializeJson](http://cfdocs.org/deserializeJson)()** to convert it to an array.

Usage:

```
Result.Data = deserializeJson(Result.Input);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific question, "

Is there a better way than striping the [], converting to a list, then converting to an array?"

Actually, once you strip away the square brackets, it is a list so that's one step less.